# Preview HTML file in Android Studio plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, android-studio-plugin

I'm creating Android Studio plugin and I need to open (preview) html file.
For now I can open HTML file using this code:

```
String file="c:\\test\\index.html";    
BrowserLauncher.getInstance().browse(file,WebBrowserManager.getInstance().getFirstActiveBrowser());
```

The problem is that this code open external webbrowser. But I would like to open this HTML file **inside** Android Studio (IntelliJ) IDE (open a new tab with HTML preview).

How can I do this?

Comment: You can try using JCEF - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/jcef.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Open In > Browser > Built-in Preview

[image]

It opens new tab in Android Studio